# Import org.springframework canot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new to Spring framework and I created a new maven project on eclipse and then added the dependencies in `pom.xml` file as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>`
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And when I am trying to import `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` in my java file it is not able to resolve `org.springframework.`

Comment: Change scope to `compile`.

Comment: It worked Thanks. @M.Deinum